# delete data from database id not present in php array

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter and I have two variable in my controller

```
$bus_code = 1;

$route_code = array('route_code' => 1,'route_code' => 3,'route_code' => 4);
```

mysql table data,

```
- id, route_code,   bus_code
 - 1,     1,             1
 - 2,     2,             2
 - 3,     3,             1
 - 4,     4,             1
 - 5,     5,             2
 - 6,     7,             2
```

I want to delete data where bus code is 1 and route code not in `$route_code` array
in CodeIgniter model

Comment: What did you try? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
$this->db->where('bus_code', $id);
$this->db->where_not_in('route_code', $route_code);
$this->db->delete('tableName');
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the help:

```
$this->db->where('bus_code', 1);
$this->db->where_not_in('route_code', $route_code);
$this->db->delete('table_name');
```

Change `table_name` with name of table.

Comment: `$this->db->where_not_in('route_code', $route_code);`  should be more like `$this->db->where_not_in('route_code', array_values($route_code));`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as given below:

```
$route_code = array('route_code' => 1,'route_code' => 3,'route_code' => 4);
$route_code_values = array_values($route_code);
$this->db->where('bus_code', 1);  // Instead of 1 you can set variable too
$this->db->where_not_in('route_code', $route_code_values); // Passing just values of routes, We have defined column in 1st argument.
$this->db->delete('tableName'); // Set table name.
```

Answer (score 0):

*Hope this will help you :*

```
$bus_code = 1;
$route_code = [1,3,4];
$this->db->where('bus_code', $bus_code);
$this->db->where_not_in('route_code', $route_code);
$this->db->delete('table_name');
```

*Note : no rows will be deleted with your current conditions given above*

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#deleting-data